# How to Remove Concrete Blocks

Tags: adhesive, demolition, concrete-block

I have a few concrete blocks hard glued together to the garage floor to create a raised platform. What is the best/easiest way to remove this without damaging the floor?

[image]

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: test the exposed glue for solubility ... also test for softening if heated

Comment: You could play around with it for a few hours, or just hit the blocks with a sledge hammer.  It is not likely there would be any damage to the concrete floor.  If there is any it would be superficial.

Comment: Have you considered a BFH?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either direct impact to the side of the blocks (possibly spread with a bit of 2x8 if you want the blocks intact) to apply a shearing force to the floor-to-block bond, or a wide (4 inch/100mm or wider) flat masonry chisel applied (with a hammer) to the joint at the bottom of the blocks, nearly parallel to the floor, to pop them up off the floor.

Answer (score 1):

I actually had to use a jack hammer I bought from Amazon for about $50 to get the job done. Took me about 45 minutes.